# ANTLR4 match multiple lines to a stop word, but don't consume it

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

I want to parse the following text file, one line is an identifier and the next (+ N lines) is the data for the identifier

```
!ident my.identifier(1)
!data my multi line
string data that can be very long
but does not have a end
!ident my.identifier(2)
!data just one line
!ident my.identifier(3)
```

later I would like to know
my.identifier=my multi line\nstring....
(so I am able to identify my identifier and the value for it)

The file starts with an identifier and then there is an alternating order of ident, data, ident, data....

I am not sure how to "start" and how to deal with the multi line thing.

My approach:

```
file: identData*;
identData: (ident) (data);
ident: IDENT field;
field: ~NL*;

data: DATA value;
value: //what happens here?


IDENT: '!ident';
DATA: '!data';

NL: '\r' '\n' | '\n' | '\r';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `!` is a proper guard character for the next `data` or `ident` statement, then just consume up to that character.

```
data: DATA value? ;
value: .*? ~[!]   ;
```

Basically, this says that `value` will match the longest string characters, including none, plus one that is not `!`.  Making `value` optional removes the requirement for `data` to have a `value`.

**Update more details**

Complete solution to read multiple data / value pairs if someone needs it:

```
allData: (dataItem)+;
dataItem: ident  identData;
ident: IDENT field;
field: ~NL*;

itendData: DATA data;
data: .*? ~IDENT;

IDENT: '!ident';
DATA: '!data';

NL: '\r' '\n' | '\n' | '\r';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer, I used       value: .*? ~'!ident'     because a ! could be a possible character in the multi line value. The parser does not stop and consumes everything to EOF. Any Ideas @GRosenberg ?

Comment: Thanks! I used the Eclipse parse tree visualization, I debugged the wrong note. Everything works now. Thank you!